Semicolon after dot not working inside and after biblatex citation
Today I noticed a weird behavior with biblatex regarding semicolons.
Consider this following MWE using biblatex, in which i try to cite two sources using the \parencites command
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{literature.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencites[][pp. 1f.]{articleA}[][]{articleB}
\end{document}

with literature.bib looking like this
@article{articleA,
    author = {NameA},
    title = {Titel A},
    year = {2024}
}
@article{articleB,
    author = {NameB},
    title = {Titel B},
    year = {2024}
}

The output is looking like this

which is wierd, since it is missing the semicolon between the two entries (after "pp. 1f.") to separate them. So I tried different things and noticed that LaTeX will not display a semicolon after a dot in the context of citations. It makes no difference wether I use biber or bibtex as a backend for biblatex.


Here is a further example by replacing the line between \begin{document} and \end{document} with
\cite[][pp. 1f.]{articleA}; \cite[][]{articleB}
resulting in

On the other hand, a single semicolon is displayed when using two semicolons
\cite[][pp. 1f.]{articleA};; \cite[][]{articleB}

or when removing the dot in "1f."
\parencites[][pp. 1f]{articleA}[][]{articleB}

I even tried placing the semicolon inside the square brackets like this
\cite[][pp. 1f.;]{articleA} \cite[][]{articleB}
which result in just a comma being displayed



Now, what is happening in all these examples? This seems very strange to me, since ".;" is not a problem in normal LaTeX. Is it suppose to be this way?
For completeness: I am using a clean MikTex installation on windows.

I realise this is just an example and that the problem is interesting in its own right, but in order to typeset "pp. 1f." you probably want to use just 1\psq as in \autocite[1\psq]{sigfridsson} (\psq will give "sq." in English by default, whereas it will give "f." in German, but you can change this by changing the sequens and sequentes bibstrings). Usually it's better to let biblatex take care of as many things as possible and try to mark up manually as little as possible.

The last case you found looks a bit off and should probably be classified as a bug https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1395. All other results are expected with the autopunct feature, because it makes biblatex cite commands scan ahead for punctuation marks to avoid punctuation clashes. The scanning ahead actually works by absorbing the following punctuation mark as if it were an argument and then acting on it.

biblatex has a rather sophisticated punctuation tracker and tries to avoid double punctuations. Sometimes that can eat a punctuation symbol. There are various commands to fine tune the effect. Use \adddot here:
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\parencites[][pp. 1f.]{doody}[][]{herrmann}

\parencites[][pp. 1f\adddot]{doody}[][]{herrmann}

\end{document}



Thanks, that seems like a fairly simple solution. Do you know what is happening, when the semicolon gets converted to a comma?

no I would have to check the code (and while that would tell me how it is done, it wouldn't explain why, ask the biblatex maintainer for this).

Sometimes it might be more convenient to have the literal . in the input instead of \adddot, in which case it can be "protected" with \isdot: \parencites[][pp. 1f.\isdot]{doody}[][]{herrmann}. (And as noted in the comment under the question for "folgende"/"sequens" you can use 1\psq no need for any manual "pp." or "f".)
